# Random UIImage selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I've created a UIImage that changes image every 8 seconds, however right now its made so that the images are hard coded in a specific order, my question is how can I untiles the arc 4 random tool or another way to make it so that the order is completely random, here is my code as is:

My .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
NSTimer *myTimer;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
}
@end
```

And in my .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

     myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:8.00 target:self     selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


_images = @[@"Background 2.png", @"Background 3.png", @"Background 4.png", @"Background   5.png", @"Background 6.png", @"Background 7.png", @"Background 9.png", @"RSGC Crest.png"];

}

- (void)changeImage
{
static int counter = 0;
if([_images count] == counter+1)
{
    counter = 0;
}
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_images objectAtIndex:counter]];

                   counter++;
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You apparently didn't read the assignment closely enough -- it's supposed to change every 10 seconds.  At least that's the other two guys read it.

Comment: @HotLicks sorry, but what the hell are you talking about

Comment: I mean the other people who are taking the same class -- they said the change was every 10 seconds.  You're at least the 3rd person to ask this question in 3 days, so obviously you're all taking the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `arc4random_uniform()` to pick a random image like this

```
int imageNumber = arc4random_uniform(8); //because you have 8 image names in the array
NSString *imageName = _images[imageNumber];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

credit to @danielbeard for using `arc4random_uniform()` instead of `arc4random()`.

Comment: Use `ar4random_uniform` to avoid modulo bias.

Comment: @Chris Loonam i am getting an error on the percentage sign (modulus) saying that its a invalid operand to binary expression

Comment: I updated my code, try now

Comment: @Chris Loonam is there a way to make it so that the first image that shows up is random right now? because right now the first image is hardcoded and then after 8 seconds it changes to a random one?